# How Left join two tables mysql

Tags: mysql, pdo

i have Three tables in database

**Category:** id, category

**Sub_category:** id, category(category.id), sub_category

**Product:** id, p_name, country, category(category.id), sub_category(sub_category.id)

when I execute this query sub_category is empty , but when I delete `LEFT JOIN cat ON product.category = cat.id` category is empty and sub_category is filled correctly

on my xamp localhost it work correctly but when i upload it on server it has the error above

```
SELECT * FROM product 
LEFT JOIN subcat ON product.sub_category = subcat.id 
LEFT JOIN cat ON product.category = cat.id 
WHERE product.id = $id


array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(16) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["p_name"]=>
    string(80) "Agusha snak"
    ["country"]=>
    string(24) "croatia"
    ["category"]=>
    string(37) "baby feed"
    ["sub_category"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share your error message.

Comment: The contents of the tables must be different. Can you show some sample data and the desired result?

Comment: @NikuNjRathod They're not getting an error message, just getting incorrect results as they described it.

Comment: yes there is no error message query executes but incorectly

Comment: there should be cookie in sub_category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have duplicate column names in the tables. The associative array returned by `fetch()` will only contain the last column with the same name.

Use aliases to distinguish them.

```
SELECT p.*, c.category AS category_name, s.sub_category AS subcategory_name
FROM product AS p
LEFT JOIN subcat AS s ON p.sub_category = s.id 
LEFT JOIN cat AS c ON p.category = c.id 
WHERE p.id = $id
```

Also, you shouldn't substitute variables into the query, use a prepared statement and `bindParam()` to protect against SQL Injection.